# Debugging information for 'mpiexec' cannot be found or doesn't match

Tags: parallel-processing, visual-studio-2015, mpi

I am going to start parallel programming using MPI on visual studio c++ 2015. I made all configurations for MPI. I want to make the call from visual studio. So I followed the steps in this [screenshot](http://supercomputingblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/configure_command_line.JPG)

and I got this error :

> Debugging information for 'mpiexec' cannot be found or doesn't
>   match.Cannot find or open the PDB file

I trying to add *MPI Cluster Debugger* in Debugger to launch list,but there is no *MPI Cluster Debugger* in the list.
What i need to do?